# Enable Service connect for ECS Service with AWS CDK v1

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I'm trying to enable Service Connect for my fargateService using AWS CDK V1

```
   const fargateService = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'MyService', {
      cluster,
      taskImageOptions: {
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(...),
        enableLogging: true,
        containerPort: XXXX,
        logDriver: logging,
        secrets: this.getSecrets(),
        environment: ...,
      },
      cpu: 512,
      memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
      taskSubnets: {
        subnets: vpc.selectSubnets({ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT }).subnets,
      },
      loadBalancer: lb,
      certificate,
      cloudMapOptions: cloudMapOptions,
    });
```

We can do it with aws cdk v2:
fargateService.enableServiceConnect('namespace')

But Is there anyway we can do it in v1? (I can't migrate to V2 yet since it will take a lot of project time)